# Simple Python headache with number comparison

Tags: python, numbers

To keep a clean question, the problem is commented inside the code :)

```
theOpenFile = open('text.txt', 'r')
highest = 0
for myCurrentString in theOpenFile.readlines():

                                          ## Simple string manipulation
    stringArray = myCurrentString.split() ## to get value, this seems to
    series = stringArray[0].split('.')[0] ## work perfectly when I
                                          ## "print series" at the end

    if series > highest:                  ## This doesn't work properly,
        highest = series                  ## although no syntantic or
        print "Highest = " + series       ## runtimes errors, just wrong output

    print series
theOpenFile.close()
```

Output

```
Highest = ï»¿8
ï»¿8
Highest = 6
6
Highest = 6
6
Highest = 8
8
Highest = 8
8
Highest = 7
7
Highest = 4
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not numbers, so things can get a bit strange. Convert your variable to a `float` or an `int` and it should work

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as theOpenFile:
    highest = 0
    for myCurrentString in theOpenFile:
        stringArray = myCurrentString.split()

        try:
            series = float(stringArray[0].split('.')[0])
        except ValueError:
            # The input wasn't a number, so we just skip it and go on
            # to the next one
            continue

        if series > highest:
            highest = series
            print "Highest = " + series

        print series
```

A cleaner way of doing it would be like this:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as handle:
    numbers = []

    for line in handle:
        field = line.split()[0]

        try:
            numbers.append(float(field))  # Or `int()`
        except ValueError:
            print field, "isn't a number"
            continue

    highest = max(numbers)
```

Comment: Your clean solution is nearly working I think :)

I made a slight modification as follows

`with open('text.txt', 'r') as handle:
    numbers = []

    for line in handle:
        field = line.split()[0]
        num = field.split('.')[0]

        print num
        

        try:
            numbers.append(float(num))  # Or `int()`
        except ValueError:
            print field, "isn't a number"
            continue

    highest = max(numbers)`

Now the problem is that I get this error

`ï»¿8
ï»¿8.2 isn't a number
6
6
8
8
7
4`

Comment: @Blender is right with the float / int conversion you should do. By the way, what you see is the [utf8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) of your file. You should `codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8-sig")` your file after `import codecs`

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Here is the working code, and also average Simpsons season ratings :D

http://pastebin.com/MnZBwSdP

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a dot before a whitespace on each non-blank line in the file:

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
  highest = max(int(line.partition('.')[0]) for line in file if line.strip())
```